# Writing numbers to a file with more precision - C++

Tags: c++, file-io, precision

I wrote some parameters (all of type `double`) to a file for use in performing some complex computations. I write the parameters to the files like so:

`refStatsOut << "SomeParam:" << value_of_type_double << endl;`
where `refStatsOut` is an `ofstream`parameter. There are four such parameters, each of type `double`. What I see as written to the file is different from what its actual value is (in terms of loss of precision). As an example, if `value_of_type_double` had a value -28.07270379934792, then what I see as written in the file is -28.0727.

Also, once these stats have been computed and written I run different programs that use these statistics. The files are read and the values are initially stored as `std::strings` and then converted to `double` via `atof` functions. This results in the values that I have shown above and ruins the computations further down.

My question is this:
1. Is there a way to increase the resolution with which one can write values (of type `double` and the like) to a file so as to NOT lose any precision?
2. Could this also be a problem of `std::string` to `double` conversion with `atof`? If so, what other function could I use to solve this?

P.S: Please let me know in case some of the details in this question are not clear. I will try to update them and provide more details.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **[setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/)** function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is there a way that I can set the precision dynamically given that the number of decimal places will be different each time? How do I do that?

Comment: @Sriram - you may want to revert to printf or fprintf, it allows flexible format specifiers. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 3):

ofstream your_file;

you can use your_file.precision(X);

The main difference between precision() and setPrecision() is that precision returns the current precision and setPrecision doesn't. Therefore, you can use precision like this.

```
streamsize old_precision = your_file.precision(X);
// do what ever you want

//restore precision
your_file.precision(old_precision);
```

Answer (score 1):

a `double` is basically a 64-bit integer, if you want a cheap way of writing it out, you can do something like this (note I'm assuming that your compiler uses `long` for 64-bit ints)

```
double value = 32985.932235;
long *saveme = (long*)&value;
```

Just beware of the caveat that the saved value may not remain the same if loaded back on a different architecture.