# digits after decimal point for double variables/calculations in C++

Tags: c++, double, latitude-longitude, precision, digit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing numbers to a file with more precision - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733046/writing-numbers-to-a-file-with-more-precision-c)

While storing latitude/longitude values as `double`, I keep ending up with variables that contain trimmed numbers -e.g.  47.2792 for 47.279229 and 8.42432 for 8.424317- What is the best way to make the variables hold all the digits without loss during both variable assignments and performing arithmetic operations -e.g. adding 0.01098901098 to 47.279229 and storing it as a new variable without any precision loss etc.-? `setprecision` handles this for streams but I have yet to find a way that will serve as its variable/math counterpart.

Comment: specifying the programming language would help...

Comment: @MirceaD. oh, forgot that one. fixing now.

Comment: How do you output your `double` numbers (or convert them to string)?

Comment: @Arkadiy well I don't output them, I only use them to create top left and bottom right latitude/longitude pairs for 1 km x 1 km grids -after giving one latitude longitude pair as starting point such as one in my question-. In order create new lat lon points for grid corners, I use a certain formula to modify the double values of latitude and longitudes. All I know is that if I wanted to output them using streams, `setprecision` would be adequate.

Comment: You need to either study numerical analysis (since in general `double` can only represent an approximation) or use an arbitrary precision library such as GNU GMP. Or maybe both.

Comment: You say that variables "contain" trimmed numbers. How are you looking at the variables? In the debugger?

Comment: @Michael Burr: certainly `double` is capable of representing 47.279229 rather than 47.2792?

Comment: @Arkadiy oh you mean that, yes I used the debugger to check them. Also, using the standard `cout` without `setprecision` yields the same.

Comment: @sm90901 - yes, because the **default** precision is 6 digits. If you want to see more (using `cout`), use `setprecision`. I don't know how to persuade the debugger to show more digits, but it's doing the same thing: rounding to 6 digits. That doesn't mean the `double` value itself only holds 6 digits. Its precision doesn't change.

Comment: `setprecision` to what? And which debugger? The reason I am asking is that I've seen double arithmetics produce way more digits, but never fewer. If you have precision problems,  I'd expect the result to look like 47.279219899999999 rather than 47.27922

Comment: @Arkadiy I use the Visual Studio 2010. As for `setprecision`, I mentioned it because I can see the trimmed digits when printing the `double` values using `cout`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I see. I guess I'll have to do some fumbling with multiplications in order to find a way around.

Comment: There! So the digits are actually correct, it's just the debugger that's wrong. The right question to ask is "How do I set the precision that VS2010 uses to display 'double' type?"

Comment: @Arkadiy Wow, that never occurred to me. Getting on it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The type `double` is internally [normally] stored as a binary floating point. In general, decimal values cannot represent exactly using binary floating point values although the original decimal values can often be restored exactly (with the exception of the right number of trailing zeros). When doing computations values close to the original values are manipulated, thereby introducing additional errors. The result of converting decimal fractional numbers to `double`, computing with these values, and converting them back will yield values close to the expected outcome but it won't be exact.

If you know the maximum of fractional digits you are going to process, you can multiply your original values by a suitable power of 10 and use integer arithmetic for your computations. To display the values you would just insert a decimal point at the appropriate location.

Comment: While this answer is perfectly correct and insightful, I don't think it applies to the situation described in the question.